# Scala: Determine the time complexity of two different implementations of the + operation on polynomials

Tags: scala, time-complexity

Let's say that a polynomial can be seen as a map from exponents to coefficients. For example, x^3 - 2x + 5 can be represented with the map `Map(0 -> 5, 1 -> -2, 3 -> 1)`. I have a class `Poly` in Scala that represents polynomials as maps. So far so good. Assume now that I have two implementations of the `+` operation on polynomials. I want to determine the time complexity of the `+` operation in each case and figure out which of the two implementations is more efficient. The implementations go as follows:

Implementation of `+` operation on `Poly` in terms of `foldLeft`

```
class Poly(terms0: Map[Int, Double]) {

  def this(bindings: (Int, Double)*) = this(bindings.toMap)

  val terms = terms0 withDefaultValue 0.0

  def + (other: Poly) = new Poly((other.terms foldLeft terms)(addTerm))

  def addTerm(terms: Map[Int, Double], term: (Int, Double)) = {
    val (exp, coeff) = term
    terms + (exp -> (coeff + terms(exp)))
  }

  override def toString = (for ((exp, coeff) <- terms.toList.sorted.reverse) 
    yield coeff + "x^" + exp) mkString " + "
}
```

Implementation of `+` operation on `Poly` in terms of `++` and `map`

```
class Poly(terms0: Map[Int, Double]) {

  def this(bindings: (Int, Double)*) = this(bindings.toMap)

  val terms = terms0 withDefaultValue 0.0

  def + (other: Poly) = new Poly(terms ++ (other.terms map adjust))

  def adjust(term: (Int, Double)): (Int, Double) = {
    val (exp, coeff) = term
    exp -> (coeff + terms(exp))
  }

  override def toString = (for ((exp, coeff) <- terms.toList.sorted.reverse) 
    yield coeff + "x^" + exp) mkString " + "
}
```

**What I've done so far**

For the first version, since the `+` operation on HashMap takes effectively constant (eC) time (according to these [performance characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)), `terms + (exp -> (coeff + terms(exp)))` takes eC time, and therefore `addTerm` takes eC time. Thus we can conclude that the `+` operation on `Poly` takes (almost?) linear time, right?

For the second version, suppose that `terms` and `other.terms` consist of n and m elements, respectively. `adjust` takes eC time, so `other.terms map adjust` takes (almost?) O(m) time. Therefore, `terms ++ (other.terms map adjust)` takes O(n) + O(m) time, right?

So which implementation is more efficient? Corrections/suggestions?

Comment: I think the constant factors involved mean that "time complexity" will not predict "more efficient". Also, in practice, how big (How many terms) will your polynomials have?

Comment: I found the problem [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OHxj6IHyts&index=6&list=PLO9y7hOkmmSGJxducP4r5XB6lNx1i2Hae#t=19m40s), so I didn't concern myself with the details, especially the input of the program in real-life situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should both take effectively linear time in the number of elements being added. Your analysis for the first version is correct, the only mistake in the second version is that `++` is not O(n) + O(m) but effectively linear in O(m). `++` is a short hand for doing `+` repeatedly, so the two version are not very different.

However, there is a `merged` method defined in `HashMap` that can do all this for you:

```
def + (other: Poly) = new Poly(terms.merged(other.terms) { (x, y) =>
  (x._1, x._2 + y._2)
})
```

But it would require that the type of `terms` be `HashMap`, which makes using `withDefaultValue` impossible because it does not return a `HashMap`.

Comment: Oh, I thought that concatenation (++) of two Maps, say `map1` and `map2`, takes time proportional to the elements of `map1`. The O(n) + O(m) time of `terms ++ (other.terms map adjust)` came from the O(n) time of map concatenation plus the O(m) time of `other.terms map adjust`, but I wasn't really sure about the analysis. The map concatenation doesn't resemble the concatenation on Lists? What's the default concrete implementation of `Map`, by the way? `HashMap`?

Comment: List concatenation can reuse the second list as the new tail but has to move all the elements of the first list - it's really a special case. `Map` is weird, with a small number of elements is uses built-in classes that store the keys and values in fields, once large enough it uses `HashMap`.

Comment: So, the `++` operation on Map takes time proportional to the elements of the map on the right side of `++`. You've made my day. :-) Thanks for your answers! It seems that the space complexity of the second version is worse (?), but that's another story. I don't really know how to argue about that. Just for the record, Martin Odersky said in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OHxj6IHyts&index=6&list=PLO9y7hOkmmSGJxducP4r5XB6lNx1i2Hae#t=19m40s) that the `foldLeft` version is more efficient, but I can't argue about that.

Comment: I agree, the second version creates an intermediate `Map` with `other.terms map adjust` so I suspect it eats more memory and is slower.